# Keep background colour of form select drop down when clicking off the form

Tags: css

I have customised a drop down.

```
<select name="country">
      <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
      <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
      <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
      <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
</select>
```

With the following CSS

```
select {
   display: none;
}

select {
   width: 8em;
   font-family: Segoeui;
   font-size: 28px;
   padding: 5px 5px;
   margin: 5px;
   display: inline-flex;
   font-weight: 300;
   outline: none;
   position: relative;
   background: #ccc;
   color: white;
   border-radius: 8px;
}

select:hover{
   background: #eb4410;
}
select:focus{
   background: #eb4410;
}
select option:selected{
   background: #eb4410; !important
}
```

It works as I wish:

Before hover over.

[image: Before hover over]

When hovering over

[image: When hovering over]

When selected:

[image: When selected]

The key problem is when I now click off somewhere else on the screen, the background colour changes to its original colour.

i.e.

When clicking off the drop down.

[image: When clicking off the drop down]

My question is 2 fold.

1) When I am selecting from the drop down, a standard blue colour appears of the option that I'm hovering over at the time (please see "When hovering over" above). How do I change that colour?

2) How do I get the box to maintain it's orange colour background after I have selected an item then click off the drop-down box (please "When clicking off the drop down" above)?

I hope to be able to solve this just using CSS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
select:not(:focus){
  background: #eb4410;  
}
```

This one answers your question on how to keep the background color when the select loses focus.

It's not easy to change the style of `<option>` elements. They are rendered by your OS, not by any HTMl or CSS code.

Comment: That doesn't quite work. The drop down is now orange at the very start. I want it to be the grey colour before anything is selected. Then once something is selected it goes orange and stays orange. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are going to write a little script.